# SQL Replace function using DAO Visual Baisc 6

Tags: sql-server, vb6, dao

I have a legacy application developed in Visual Basic 6. I have to update a select query to use SQL's Replace function, but as soon as I use the same DAO crashes while opening recordset with "Replace is an unrecognized function" error. My Query is as follows and work fine on SQL server:

[image]

I tried to create a user defined function in the database but still no luck. Is there any way I can run a replace function in VB6.

Comment: which driver/Provider are you using for the database Connection?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to put the SQL in rather than a screenshot?

Comment: DAO to which database?